# How I can show icons/pics with other records with SqlConnection? C#

Tags: c#, icons, sqlconnection

I want to show pics/icons with records from the database, I'm using SqlConnection to connect with the database like that:

```
public IList<Danie> GetDish()
        {
            var result = new List<Dish>();
            using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RestaurantCN"].ConnectionString))
            {
                var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Dish", sqlCon);
                sqlCon.Open();

                var dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var newDish = new Dish
                    {
                        IdDish = (int)dr["IdDish"],
                        Name = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                        Price = (int)dr["Price"]
                    };
                    result.Add(newDish);
                }
                dr.Dispose();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

How can I do this? I should set this into database or I can set this into a file and link with that?

Comment: Do you want to keep orginal images or images location?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to overcome this problem. For one option you can save pic or icon to database with bits or something .

The another and easiest way is keep pictures locations. For instance

```
/Images/example.png
```

You can access pictures

```
public IList<Danie> GetDish()
        {
            var result = new List<Dish>();
            using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RestaurantCN"].ConnectionString))
            {
                var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Dish", sqlCon);
                sqlCon.Open();

                var dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    var newDish = new Dish
                    {
                        IdDish = (int)dr["IdDish"],
                        Name = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                        Price = (int)dr["Price"]
                        ImagePath= (string)dr["Image"]
                    };
                    result.Add(newDish);
                }
                dr.Dispose();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Now you have images so your Uı or html code can access this pictures from list